# Multiple Linq query ||

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I've done a search function in which I want to search for products either by `ProductName` or by `Category`. I want to do this in one LINQ query. At the moment I can search on `Category` but I want to add functionality to my query for searching `ProductName` as well. I believe I should use the `||` or `&&` operator somewhere but I can't get it to work.

E.g. to check if string searchProducts matches s.Category or s.ProductName:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchProducts))
{
    products = products.Where(s => s.Category.Contains(searchProducts)).OrderBy(s => s.Category);

    return View(products.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
}
```

Peace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
products = products.Where(s => s.Category.Contains(searchProducts) 
                         || s.ProductName.Contains(searchProducts))
```

Comment: Oh yeah forgot the "Contains" for s.ProductName. Not on my a-game today. Thanks.

Comment: you can also use StartsWith if you want to match productname